# How to let a random amount of time pass with Yampa

Tags: haskell, frp, yampa

I'm trying to write a simple FRP sample with Yampa that instead of waiting for 2 seconds (like here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Yampa/reactimate) will wait for a random amount of time within some bounds. I have tried multiple different approaches to somehow get the randomRIO function into the signal function but can't realy grasp what I am supposed to do.
My intention is to replace the twoSecondsPassed function somewhat like this:

```
randomTimePassed :: SF () Bool
randomTimePassed = time >>> arr (\x -> x < randomRIO (0, 10))
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick because of a type missmatch.
The compiler outputs:

```
* Couldn't match type `m0 a0' with `Double'
  Expected: SF Time Bool
    Actual: SF (m0 a0) Bool
* In the second argument of `(>>>)', namely
    `arr (\ x -> x < randomRIO (0, 10))'
  In the expression: time >>> arr (\ x -> x < randomRIO (0, 10))
  In an equation for `randomTimePassed':
      randomTimePassed = time >>> arr (\ x -> x < randomRIO (0, 10))
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as I'm very new to Yampa and can't seem to find a proper documentation to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `randomRIO (0,10)` is (specialized as you're using it) `IO Double`, but the type of `2`, which you're replacing, is simply `Double`.  Furthermore, you can't do `IO` actions from within a yampa `SF`.

What you'll need to do is generate your number (or perhaps generate a *generator* for your number) outside of the `SF` and pass it in as an argument.  For instance, you can write:

```hs
someTimePassed :: Double -> SF () Bool
someTimePassed t = time >>> arr (\x -> x < t)

main = do
  t <- getCurrentTime
  timeRef <- newIORef t
  randTime <- randomRIO (0, 10)
  reactimate initialize (sense timeRef) actuate (someSecondsPassed randTime)
```

---

If you're going to need multiple random numbers, you'll want to pass a random number generator.  You can generate one using, for instance [`getStdGen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.0/docs/System-Random.html#v:getStdGen).  Furthermore, rather than writing your own `SF` to use it, you could pass it to something like [`occasionally`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Yampa-0.13.1/docs/FRP-Yampa-Random.html#v:occasionally), which produces events every so often.